# Android - Unifying duplicate styles in styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, layout, styles, screen-density

in my Android app I have style divided into density-related files (ldpi, mdpi, ...). The problem is, some of these styles are the same accross the every one of these files. I'd like to ask, is there a way to unify these styles in one central xml file and than e.g. include it in these files? 
Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the styles are only for different dimension/sizes per screen size/density you could make a dimens.xml containing only the dimension and put those in put those in the corresponding resource folder.

else you could make 1 root style xml and only override the specify style you want per per screen size/density.

So in res/values you would have style.xml containing style A, style B, style C, style D.

and for ldpi you want a different style B only. You only have to create a res/values-ldpi folder with styles.xml containing only style B.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
--- values
    -- styles.xml (define unique style and custom style extending that unique style)

--- values-v21 and so on..
    -- styles.xml (custom style extending values/styles.xml's unique style)
```

and apply `custom style`, all the `unique items` will go under `unique style` and the `customized` ones will go under `custom style`..